# Cannot read property JQUERY array data

Tags: php, jquery, null

I'm trying to verify data.announce but i'm getting this error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'announce' of null"

So here is my code

**php file:**

```
  $return = array("msg" => "You'll recive an email with instructions!");
  return json_encode($return);
```

**jquery:**

```
$("form[id='common-handler/register'] #submit").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if(locked == 1)
            return false;
        locked = 1;

        var _form = $(this).closest('form').attr('id');
        $.post("/"+_form, $(this).closest('form').serialize(), function(data) {
            if(!isEmpty(data.announce))
                $("#search_bar").html(data.msg).fadeIn("slow");
            else
                $("form[id='" + _form + "'] p.msg").text(data.msg);
        }, "json");
    });


function isEmpty(str) {
    return (!str || 0 === str.length);
}
```

Comment: 1. PHP file needs to echo the result, not return it. 2. you should json encode the echo'd message, and in jquery, use $.parseJSON(data) to turn it into a javascript object.

Comment: @kennypu #2: you don't need to parseJSON if you provide the json datatype, which he has done.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot return data in a PHP file, unless you're including it somewhere in another PHP file, so you will need this to get your `$.post()`, working via JSON output:

```
echo json_encode(array("msg" => "You'll recive an email with instructions!"));
exit(0);
```

Comment: why are you putting a zero in the exit function.

Comment: @user1681542 - will not output an error and will stop the execution.. more on: http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php

Comment: as I said above everything's working fine without that statement "if(!isEmpty(data.announce))"

Comment: @Anonymous' If it's working fine, it's working fine wrongly. The error you are getting says `data` == `null` and `null` doesn't have an `announce` property.

Comment: just add "announce" to the output array, and that's it men!

Comment: @ZlatanO. that's why i'm here to find wtf is wrong with this... :P

Comment: As it should, because you're trying to act on a property of `null`, but `null` can't have properties. Did you make the change Zlatan O. suggested? it should fix most of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
return $return = json_encode( array( "announce" => array("msg" => "You'll recive an email with instructions!") ) );
```

Comment: I don't want announce in my array. Everything's working fine without that statement "if(!isEmpty(data.announce))"

Answer (score 0):

You don't have "announce" as one of the keys in the array you are returning, only "msg"

You want:

```
array("msg" => "You'll recive an email with instructions!", "announce"=>"My announcement");
```

Comment: Notice, it said announce of **null**, that means `data` is null. the missing announce property is the least of his worries.

Comment: @KevinB You're right.. announce is null. I don't want it in my array.

Comment: @Anonymous' No, announce isn't null, announce is `undefined`. `data` is null, which means your php script did not return any json.

Comment: If I remove that statement it works.. so json is returned by php file

Answer (score -1):

Try changing:

if(!isEmpty(data.announce))

to:

if(null == data.announce)